# MVC event recording last activity

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I am trying to record a user's last request/ last active time using MVCEvent. I would want to record the User Id and the time in a database table. The function I am using is in Module.php file in "public function onBootstrap($e)". I am not sure How can i pass user ID in module.php as I am not using session, I am using a SOAP protocol. Any example of it would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Which system of authentication are you using ?

Comment: I am using Zend Authentication service

Comment: Can you post your Boot Strap Function?